# How to pass multiple parameters as single object in a function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How could I pass multiple parameters as single object in a function?

Example:

```
function getBankEditActionColumn( setAction, setActionRow, worldReadyContext, setwithdrawalThreshold, setwithdrawalThresholdData, legalCountryCode, tier, showThreshold, fptiData){....}
```

I need to have `setAction`, `setActionRow`, `setwithdrawalThreshold`, `setwithdrawalThresholdData`, `showThreshold` in a single object defined as:

```
  setAction: { (value: React.SetStateAction<string>): void; (arg0: string): void },

  setActionRow: { (value: React.SetStateAction<{}>): void; (arg0: BankAsset): void },

  setwithdrawalThreshold: { (value: React.SetStateAction<boolean>): void },

  setwithdrawalThresholdData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<{}>>,

  showThreshold: boolean,
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If they're in a single object pass that object? If they're not in a single object put them in one, e.g., `{ setAction, setActionRow, ... }` using object shorthand. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass them as an object.

```
const obj = {
   setAction, 
   setActionRow, 
   worldReadyContext, 
   setwithdrawalThreshold, 
   setwithdrawalThresholdData, 
   legalCountryCode, 
   tier, 
   showThreshold, 
   fptiData
 }

function(obj){...}
```

To access them in the function, just destructure the object.

```
function(obj) {
   const {setAction, setActionRow, ...rest} = obj
 // do something
   return
}
```